# How do We pick 2 Files in a single route in Apache Camel, and process them simultaneously?

Tags: java, apache, routes, apache-camel

I have 2 files at the same file location.....  I want both the files to be picked up at the same time, so that I can get hold of both in my Processor at the same time...

I am using Apache Camel for routing.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to your problem depends a lot of the cirumstances.

If you can predict the file names you can easily use a [pollEnrich](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) together with an [aggregation strategy](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/processor/aggregate/AggregationStrategy.html).

The aggregation strategy gives you a method like this

`Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange,Exchange newExchange)`

so that you can decide how to deal with the two files. `oldExchange` is the original exchange, `newExchange` will be the exchange from the enriching URI.

Pseudo code example:

```
from("file:inbox?fileName=invoices.csv")
  .pollEnrich("file:inbox2?fileName=customers.xml" strategyRef="myAggregationStrategy")
  .bean(someTransformerBean)
  .to("file:outbox?fileName=report.xml");
```